# get from Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging app.config log fileName

Tags: logging, enterprise-library

Im using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.
The log fileName setting is located at App.Config file.

I want get this fileName property by code.
I didnt find how to get it.
Is it possible? How can I do it?
I`m working with C#.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the name of the listener in the configuration and the type then you can extract the information:

```
IConfigurationSource configSource = ConfigurationSourceFactory.Create();

var logSettings = configSource.GetSection(LoggingSettings.SectionName) as LoggingSettings;

var listener = logSettings.TraceListeners
    .SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name == "Rolling Flat File Trace Listener");

if (listener != null)
{
    var fileListener = listener as RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData;

    if (fileListener != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fileListener.FileName);
    }
}
```

The above is for RollingFlatFileTraceListener.

Or if you just want to get the file names for all trace listeners that support the FileName property you can do this:

```
IConfigurationSource configSource = ConfigurationSourceFactory.Create();

var logSettings = configSource.GetSection(LoggingSettings.SectionName) as LoggingSettings;

foreach (var listener in logSettings.TraceListeners)
{
    PropertyInfo property = listener.GetType().GetProperty("FileName");

    if (property != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            string.Format("FileName for Trace Listener '{0}'={1}", 
                listener.Name, property.GetValue(listener, null)));
    }
}
```